# Syntax error; Undefined control sequence \EndIf

Tags: syntax

I get the following error when I compile:

```
Syntax error; Undefined control sequence \EndIf
```

Code:

```
\usepackage{algorithm2e} 

\begin{algorithm}[h]
\label{FecEncodeAndSendFECUnits}
\caption{Function for Receiving and FEC-decoding FEC-encoded Units of Data}
\KwIn{}
%\KwOut{codeRate}

         nrOfPacketsReceived = 0             HIGHEST\_FEC\_UNIT\_NR\_DECODED\_GLOBAL=0          \While{$true$}
            currentPacket = ListenToSocketForNewPkt ()              $ nrOfPacketsReceived++ $               $ currentFecUnit =ExtractValueOfPktHeader(currentPacket, FEC_UNIT_GLOBAL) $                 $ currentFecUnitModulo$ = $currentFecUnit$ \% NR\_OF\_PARALLELL\_FEC\_UNITS\_GLOBAL $               $ currentSymbolNr$ = ExtractValueOfPktHeader($currentPacket$, SYMBOL\_NR\_GLOBAL) $                   packetForCurrentFecUnitGlobal[$currentFecUnitModulo$][$currentSymbolNr$] = ExtractDataOfPkt ($currentPacket$)                 \If { $ currentFecUnit$ > $HIGHEST_FEC_UNIT_NR_DECODED_GLOBAL$ OR
            ( currentFecUnit == 0 AND   nrOfPacketsReceived == 1 ) }
              ExtractPktHeaderAndPutIntoGlobalFecUnitHeaderValues () 
            \EndIf

             \If {currentFecUnit > HIGHEST\_FEC\_UNIT\_NR\_DECODED\_GLOBAL }            
                lastFecUnitModulo  = (currentFecUnit -1 ) \% NR\_OF\_PARALLELL\_FEC\_UNITS\_GLOBAL                      DecodeFECUnit (lastFecUnitModulo, nrOfSrcSymbolsGlobal[lastFecUnitModulo], nrOfTotalSymbolsGlobal[lastFecUnitModulo], symbolSizeGlobal[lastFecUnitModulo], rateOfRedundantPkts[lastFecUnitModulo]) \\

                $ HIGHEST\_FEC\_UNIT\_NR\_DECODED\_GLOBAL++$ \  
             \EndIf

        \EndWhile               

\end{algorithm}
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: Hi Anders, [welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) `:)` I'm confused, I took a look at the `algorithm2e` documentation and found no occurrences of both `\EndIf` and `\EndWhile`. It seems the correct syntax of both `\While` and `\If` is slightly different than the one you are using.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no `\EndIf` nor `\EndWhile`; you have to use parentheses to specify the scope:

```
\If{<condition>}{<instructions>}
\While{<condition>}{<instructions>}
```

So, in your case, you could use (I wasn't sure whether to insert or not line change commands `\\` at some points):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm2e} 

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}[h]
\label{FecEncodeAndSendFECUnits}
\caption{Function for Receiving and FEC-decoding FEC-encoded Units of Data}
\KwIn{}
%\KwOut{codeRate}

         nrOfPacketsReceived = 0              HIGHEST\_FEC\_UNIT\_NR\_DECODED\_GLOBAL=0 \\
        \While{$true$}{
            currentPacket = ListenToSocketForNewPkt ()                 $ nrOfPacketsReceived++ $                 $ currentFecUnit =ExtractValueOfPktHeader(currentPacket, FEC_UNIT_GLOBAL) $                 $ currentFecUnitModulo$ = $currentFecUnit$ \% NR\_OF\_PARALLELL\_FEC\_UNITS\_GLOBAL $                 $ currentSymbolNr$ = ExtractValueOfPktHeader($currentPacket$, SYMBOL\_NR\_GLOBAL) $                   packetForCurrentFecUnitGlobal[$currentFecUnitModulo$][$currentSymbolNr$] = ExtractDataOfPkt ($currentPacket$) \\
            \If{ $ currentFecUnit$ > $HIGHEST_FEC_UNIT_NR_DECODED_GLOBAL$ OR
            ( currentFecUnit == 0 AND   nrOfPacketsReceived == 1 ) }{
              ExtractPktHeaderAndPutIntoGlobalFecUnitHeaderValues () 
            }

             \If {currentFecUnit > HIGHEST\_FEC\_UNIT\_NR\_DECODED\_GLOBAL }{            
                lastFecUnitModulo  = (currentFecUnit -1 ) \% NR\_OF\_PARALLELL\_FEC\_UNITS\_GLOBAL                      DecodeFECUnit (lastFecUnitModulo, nrOfSrcSymbolsGlobal[lastFecUnitModulo], nrOfTotalSymbolsGlobal[lastFecUnitModulo], symbolSizeGlobal[lastFecUnitModulo], rateOfRedundantPkts[lastFecUnitModulo]) \\

                $ HIGHEST\_FEC\_UNIT\_NR\_DECODED\_GLOBAL++$ \  
             }
        }               
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As a side note, the [`algorithmicx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx) package could be of interest for you; it has great functionality and it is highly customizable.

Answer (score 8):

You are mixing packages `algorithm2e` (`\KwIn`) with package `algorithmicx`. The latter
uses

```
\If{<body>}
  <then block>
\EndIf
% also with else branches
\While{<condition>}
  <body>
\EndWhile
```

whereas package `algorithm2e` provides

```
\If{<condition>}{<then block>}
\While{<condition>}{<body>}
```

and lots of other forms.

Decide, which package you want to use and read its documentation.